# Getting Error Installing SQL Server 2019 in Windows 11

Tags: sql-server, windows, installation, sql-server-2019

I am trying to install SQL Server 2019 in Windows 11. I am getting the following error for database engine and SQL Server Replication:

```
Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x851A001A
  Error description:             Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=15.0.4013.40&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026

  Feature:                       SQL Server Replication
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x851A001A
  Error description:             Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=15.0.4013.40&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026

  Feature:                       SQL Browser
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Writer
  Status:                        Passed
```

Can someone help?

Comment: I have tried these links:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538089/wait-on-the-database-engine-recovery-handle-failed-check-the-sql-server-error-l
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48532323/sql-server-express-2017-fails-install-0x851a001a
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613094/wait-on-the-database-engine-recovery-handle-failed-sql-server-2012-installatio
https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/01/27/sql-server-sql-installation-fails-error-code-0x851a001a-wait-database-engine-recovery-handle-failed/

Comment: This is a known issue, I have written more about it (and how to fix it) on the DBA sister site: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/308370/5273

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation (linked later) Windows 11 does now support SQL Server 2019. The [revision](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/commit/4afa5cb417e65008e2898402828585a81715e096#diff-ba17f3f68b7debbaa2f1dc5bebef97c21edfc108bfc81e1209f722c74a617bb2) of the documentation for this occured on 13 December. *Leaving original answer below.*

---

*The following does not reflect the latest documentation, which was changed after this answer was posted.*

SQL Server 2019 is not supported on Windows 11 at this time. This is documented, in [SQL Server 2019: Hardware and software requirements - Operating system support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server-ver15?view=sql-server-ver15#operating-system-support) by the omission of Windows 11. As a result any successful attempts to get it running on such an OS would likely be unsupported.

The "solution" is the use an operating system that is supported (see link above). You can either downgrade your install of Windows back to 10 or install afresh. Otherwise you could use a VM with a supported operating system or use a [Linux] container such as Docker (Windows Sub System for Linux (WSL) is [not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver15#prerequisites)).

Hopefully support will be added, but it may well not be, and you'll have to wait for SQL Server 2022 some time next year.

Comment: Currently, Windows 11 supports Sql Server 2019 (EXPRESS) only. I think, no support for Sql Server 2019 (MSSQL) yet.

Comment: @YeasinAbedin I link to the documentation, you could have checked. Since I posted this answer Windows 11 is supported apart from for Web and Enterprise editions.

Answer (score 0):

If still need answers, SQL Server 2019 and previous versious have issues to install on Windows 11 because of the encryption of hard drive by BitLocker.
To skip this problem, there's 2 simple ways :

- install on a second physical drive (both services and database files)
- create a virtual HD using Disk management, with MBR parition, then install SQL Server on it