# The SQL Server feature 'SQL_Engine_Core_Inst' error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019, sql-server-2019-express

For few days I am getting an issue with SQL Server 2019 Express Installation. When installing SQL Server I get an error and the server won't work. I've tried repairing it but I've got also an error here.
The following error is :

```
  Feature:                       Database Engine Services

  Status:                        Failed

  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.

  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.

  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features

  Component error code:          0x84B40002

  Error description:             The SQL Server feature 'SQL_Engine_Core_Inst' is not in a supported state for repair, as it was never successfully configured. Only features from successful installations can be repaired. To continue, remove the specified SQL Server feature.

  Error help link:               (Link that doesn't work)
```

My SQL Server Management Studio 2018 also don't work. I've tried uninstalling and installing SQL Server but it doesn't help. I've even tried uninstalling and installing Windows but nothing to do.

Comment: Just to be clear, you did a fresh install of windows and still get this error?

Comment: have you a recovery point before the first install of sql server, then go there and start new , have disabled any antivirus software?

Comment: @sniperd Yes the problem persiste even on a fresh install

Comment: @nbk I only have Windows Defender, you want me to disable it and try again ?

Comment: no windows defender would not block it, try sql developer version instead and have you checked for hardware errors in the event log?

Comment: Maybe there is a language version difference causing it?  Or is windows on a virtual machine?  I'd skip Express and just go right to Developer, it is also free.  I'm shocked that a fresh install of windows has this error.

Comment: @nbk I've tried installing dev with normal install, at the end I got error : "Unable to install SQLServer (setup.exe)" and thats all, no more informations.
Then I've tried the custom install, it says Windows Firewall Warning. I've tried opening ports with the documentation but nothing happened, so I skipped this message and continue the install. At the end I had this error : https://pastebin.com/dAEQBLLr
And SQL Server is still not working...

Comment: @sniperd As said above, I've tried installing dev version, it doesn't work at all.
Do you think French language on my computer may cause SQL Server to crash?

Comment: have you installed all updates via windows update also take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70270638/getting-error-installing-sql-server-2019-in-windows-11

Comment: Well I updated my Windows yes, and W11 is supported because it works on my gaming computer but not on my laptop. I also tried installing it on another disk and got that error : (If you want I can put all the details.txt file) https://pastebin.com/MDWWQxc8
But its all the same issues again and again since 1 week, I am running out of idea...

Comment: Then the cpu isn't supported have you check all requirements

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb and go with one of the following: 1) It may be expecting English Windows 2) I don't know if it cares, is the windows install legit 3) Does the computer meet the minimum SQL requirements (I bet it does since you game) 4) Do you have a wacky CPU 5) Is the windows install non-standard (windows installed on drive D or something) 6) Version of windows is something non-standard (not just language but accessibility or region locked weird)  -- just seems super strange that fresh windows install, and then fresh SQL blows up like that, never seen that before.

Comment: Windows 11 does have some issues installing SQL Server. I seem to remember some issue surrounding block size on certain NVME drives. Have you tried redownloading the installer again with the latest version? I believe some fixes were made. Also make sure Windows is fully up to date before installing and you have all the correct drivers for your hardware

Comment: @sniperd 
1) I've tried changing to english but it doesn't work. But I don't think it could be an issue because I use a French Windows 11 Version on my stationnary computer and it works.
2) Windows is installed via a USB Key that I created using Media Tools
3) It does meet minimum SQL requierements yep
4) I have an R5 5600H
5) Windows is installed on C: drive as usual
6) Touched nothing here

I've installed W10 (French Version) and it worked on it. Then when I wanted to upgrade to W11 via the Update Tool, the services don't start... 
I don't know what going on tbh

Comment: @Charlieface If I understand, I need my sector sizes to be between 512 and 4Kb, which is the case. I only have one disk, I also tried installing it on another one but it changed nothing...

Comment: FINALLY FIXED IT!
It seams to be a hard drive issue. To fix it I had to create a Virtual Hard Drive with the Disk Manager. Then I install SQL Server on it and it works now on Windows 11. Thanks for help everyone !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue:
If you run into that error, try creating a Virtual Hard Drive with Disk Manager. Then install SQL Server 2019 on it and it should maybe resolve the problem. If not, read all the comments and check if something helps.

Edit: When you shut down your computer, if you restart it, the virtual disk disappears. You have to mount it again and start the database engine manually. I recommend creating a script that does this for you.

Comment: That's a crazy workaround, not a real solution to the problem